# Object of type Cart is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a products model and a cart model. There is a ManyToMany relation that I put in cart model.
I am trying to return the object of cart model along with the context dictionary but it is giving this error "Object of type Cart is not JSON serializable".
I am using Django version '3.0.7'.

I am following Justing Michael's Tutorial,He is using lower Django version and its working on that.
Did Django change this thing?

```
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self,request):
        cart_id = request.session.get('cart_id')
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id = cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj  = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj  = Cart.objects.new_cart(user = request.user)
            new_obj   = True
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj
        return cart_obj,new_obj

    def new_cart(self,user=None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)
```

and the model actually is:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True) 
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product,blank=True)
    #more fields
```

and views.py is:

```
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj,new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    context={'cart':cart_obj}
    return render(request,'carts/cart_home.html',context)
```

Comment: `request.session` can only store simple data structure like list, dict, can not be used to store model instance object. change your code to `request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id`, next time you get your `cart_obj` through `Cart.objects.get(id=request.session['cart_id'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can't send a Python class instance (such as a Model class instance) as a render data, you must send a json like object (a dict in Python).

So what you need is to convert `cart_obj` to a dict so it can be sent to the frontend through a `render`. The easiest way to do it with Django is to use a [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) (In your case, the best option is a `ModelSerializer`).

```
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj,new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    cart_obj_dict = CartSerializer(cart_obj).data
    context={'cart':cart_obj_dict}
    return render(request,'carts/cart_home.html',context)
```

Comment: Sorry, I had made some mistake, I will compare the previous code with new code and update by tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to disturb you guys,I had made an idiotic mistake:

```
request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj
```

I was trying to assign cart object to session variable which was a typo ,instead in reality I should have done this:

```
request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
```

Credits:  minglyu